# whats wrong with this linked list for counting

Tags: c++

THs following code is crashing, and I'm unsure why. Trying to count the number of times an integer is found in the following linked list..However xcode keeps saying the int count=0 from the main  is breaking a thread?

```
 #include <iostream>  
 using namespace std;

struct Node {
  int val;
  Node *next;
};


  int countNum (Node *head, int key);
  Node* cons (int x, Node* p);

   int main()
   {

     Node *head = (1,cons(2,cons(2,(cons(4,(cons(5,nullptr)))))));

     int counts=0;

     counts= countNum(head,2);

     cout<< counts<< head;

     return 0;
 }

  Node* cons (int x, Node* p){

        Node *q=new Node;
        q->val=x;
        q->next=p;

    return p;
 }

 int countNum (Node *head, int key) {
         int count=0;

        if (head==nullptr)
             return 0;

         Node *follow=head;

          while (follow!=nullptr) {

                if(follow->val==key)
                   count++;

                follow=follow->next;

          }

            cout<<count;
           return count;
    }
```

Comment: `cons` should return the newly allocated `Node*` `q`

Comment: @simonc changed that, but still crashes

Comment: The change I noted is necessary but not sufficient.  goldcode has posted the remainder of the fix.

Comment: @simonc even with that adjustment the program still crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Node *head = **cons**(1,cons(2,cons(2,(cons(4,(cons(5,nullptr)))))));

Comment: thank you for that catch, but still crashes....specifically the issue is counts=countNum(head,2);

Comment: Node* cons (int x, Node* p){

        Node *q=new Node;
        q->val=x;
        q->next=p;

    return **q**;
 }

Comment: i did that as well, can you run it on your end, I'm not familiar with threads and that is the error.

Comment: compiled and run at my end. program runs fine after **both** changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return a pointer to the current node instead of the next node. Also I don't think you can do:

```
Node *head = (1, ptrToNextNode);
```

Something like this might work:

```
struct Node *head = malloc(sizeof (struct Node));
head->value = 1;
head->next = cons(2,cons(2,(cons(4,(cons(5,nullptr))))));
```

...

```
Node* cons (int x, Node* p)
{

    Node *q=new Node;
    q->val=x;
    q->next=p;

    return q;
}
```